# find where or which line error is occur while running in Batch Script?

Tags: windows, batch-file, syntax-error, error-logging

I want to know error line number where error was occure by batch script and also i want to print whole line in batch script?

```
set t=%date%_%time%
set x=FORD_DLCM_T6_FTC
set a="%m%\%x%"
cd  /d "C:\PRQA\PRQA-Framework-2.1.2\common\bin"
qacli admin --set-license-server 5055@00.00.0.0 || goto :error
qacli admin --debug-level DEBUG || goto :error
goto :EOF
:error
set remark= %ERRORLEVEL%
set status= Failure
echo ProjectName: %x%
echo Status: %status%
echo Remark: %remark%
echo Date: %t%
echo %x%,%status%,traceback(),%t% > "C:\Test\Build.csv"
echo Failed with error #%errorlevel%.
exit /b %errorlevel%
```

can any one help me out?

Comment: Are you looking for something like this: [How to get the current line number?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4609390)

Comment: Yes, quit slimier  but what i'm expecting is.....  i want to get line number where error occur and assigned to variable. can you help me out?

Comment: Have you checked out the accepted answer?? the error line is already stored in a variable...

Comment: i'm bit confused, can you please explain...  here??@aschipfl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jeb has described how the search for the right line works. in the event of an error, a call is triggered and the parameters are a unique string and an offset, which points to the number of missing lines to the correct line. Findstr looks for the unmistakable string and prints that line number. With the settlement that's right again.

I've put together some macros to show that there are other ways to read the right line.

```
@echo off
setlocal
set prompt=$g$s
call :setAllmacros
(call)
 rem begin in echo off - what line is it please ?
%ID-1:##==rem?% 
(call )
%ID-1:##==call%
set/a+
%ID-1:##==001% call :ErrorLogging Line:%%L Errorlevel:%errorlevel% 
echo 2

(call) || %ID-0:##==2% call :Errorlogging Line:%%L Errorlevel:%%errorlevel%% 
echo %errorlevel%
find /n  || %ID-0:##==003% call :Errorlogging Line:%%L Errorlevel:%%errorlevel%% 

%ID-0:##==008%
pushG 556
%ID-1:##==004% call :ErrorLogging Line:%%L Errorlevel:%errorlevel% 

%Line#print%:33=="

pause
exit /b

:errorlogging
@echo on
rem %*
@echo off
exit /b

:setAllmacros
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
(set ^"lf=^
%== define LF + CR ==%
)
for /f %%i in ('copy /z "%~f0" nul') do set "CR=%%i"

 rem Prints the fullline itself with LineNumber into stderr
 rem  usage: %Line#print%:UniqueID"
 rem   command || %Line#print%:01"
set "Line#print= @ <"%~f0" >&2 find /n "%%Line#print%%"

 rem Read the fullline BEFORE into Variables with LineNumber; do something ... 
 rem  usage: command 1 line before
 rem         %ID-1:##==01% [command %%L ... %%M ...]
set ID-1=  if errorlevel 1 for /f "usebackQtokens=1*delims=:" %%L in (^
 `cmd /v /c ^"findstr /n /r /c:"..*^!CR^!*^!LF^!.*ID-1:.#^=^##%%" "%~f0"^"`) do ^>^&2 echo BatchLine: %%L -- %%M ^& 

 rem Read the fullline itself into Variables with LineNumber; do something ... 
 rem  usage: command || %ID-0:##==01% [command %%L ... %%M ...]
set ID-0= @ for /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%L in ('findstr /n /r /c:"ID-0:.#=##%%" "%~f0"') do ^>^&2 echo BatchLine: %%L -- %%M ^& 
exit /b
```

hope it helps

Phil